i am not able to connect to ganache what should i do i am gettinng a error like this
the error is 

 node deploy.js
Deploying, please wait...
JsonRpcProvider failed to detect network and cannot start up; retry in 1s (perhaps the URL is wrong or the node is not started)
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7545
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 7545
}


//synchronous [solidity] - doing one by  one
//asynchronous [javascrript] - doing at  the same time

//cooking

const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
//syncronous
//1.
async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x11a8b8c46de5bac67bcb5fabc57f1b1a558d18ea0d764dc1ad25bc33a0cf4a60",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  //get number
  const currentFavouriteNumber = await contract.retreive();
  console.log(currentFavouriteNumber);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

//cook popcorn
//pour drinks
//start  movie

async function SetUpMovieNight() {
  await cookPopcorn();
  await pourDrinks();
  startMovie();
}

and i tried by uninstalling app and tried cli also but giving error i am using yarn in windows ,help me with this
i tried using chatgpt lines , i tried using several prompts in command prompt, i disabled antivirus and firewall and also checked when i use this prompt
'''
ganache-cli -p 7545
'''
i am getting this in my prompt 
'''
Available Accounts
(0) 0x69384E41ff1eeef0C57A2e2c5E8b6D8Ef68557b0 (100 ETH)
(1) 0x4bc428277C970A1F13b04cBd26A0BBcA2b939676 (100 ETH)
(2) 0xaF04EaCf5466d3F14060351ed20CfBA2850313B3 (100 ETH)
(3) 0xD2B3960581D032c6cF7915D2A3702890B4E1fd36 (100 ETH)
(4) 0x3caE04c8F172a6010B6daa25e6DD2ce8a0190299 (100 ETH)
(5) 0x9c7493f93d7E57Dd78101c82dE686A2B5bBb9f91 (100 ETH)
(6) 0xb4eccE234b1C47b8DB3D6ACbCC8FA31C9D1d730E (100 ETH)
(7) 0x047d4E484381F44AFa1075b2b34B97889b387B88 (100 ETH)
(8) 0xe41d72C0DCE650Ca86C86060d667f6DA58995130 (100 ETH)
(9) 0x06C8D826Da9C0Ce7De5af64E062E414ABeb2693e (100 ETH)
Private Keys
(0) 0xb5583ffab2fe0b5d09316c29a97b1ba400669d3e078a2b65bb77f170e8987181
(1) 0xae5555417195a22e86256a5aed72798c506d6cca3251231650405d672a266126
(2) 0x37720481cffa69e91de34cc172ee549b4879544e902e5ead339b233aa4c686c8
(3) 0x345cfc6665b0fb91d96a2091251234372507bf3d02972ca3c4ea72db9ce881ee
(4) 0x0d9e4e0234c830ac2bbe7f6c132f7339068ed1c9518d57cf8d624195f00359b8
(5) 0x3e932e22198fe9583ea623894325d9f6392e94ebbd001e685743917b3c6b2c7a
(6) 0x604df656722939e4b2ee8fb9eaa8e3cf684430a990ce8614983b43d7b57df141
(7) 0xf3ef23bca26841958d2ffb55eac2d585f2bfaba758c91c117c720feda14b1309
(8) 0xd43e9680c48a75699c1d9a54a6c6bfa2081a0bbb21148c88762b0527d5f89903
(9) 0xa0c2527755dbec2a82371a474ba31e7cf95c1cb6227d9bcc6ed5b6719647744e
HD Wallet
Mnemonic:      curious actor quick spirit garlic popular kiwi feel core surge correct luxury
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}
Gas Price
20000000000
Gas Limit
6721975
Call Gas Limit
9007199254740991
Listening on 127.0.0.1:7545
'''
help me with this
